# Ksoap2 Can not serialize Integer Array List

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am using Ksoap2 to send and get response from the server using soap services. 
I am sending complex type of object. For this I have serialize the whole class. but the one property of class is Integer List.

So i am getting the following error while requesting to the server

> Can not Serialize [12, 11, 225, 3252,] // which is my integer array

**so here is my Class which implements KvmSerializeable**

```
public class EnrollmentModel implements KvmSerializable {
   .....
 // different fields 
 public List<Integer> ClassIdsHavingLevels; // this is the list field 

 // setting property like 
 @Override
public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    switch (index) {
    ...... 
    case 13:   // is it the right way 
            ClassIdsHavingLevels.add((Integer) value);
            break;
   .........

  @Override   
public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch (index) {
    .......  
   case 13:  // is the right way in getPropertyInfo 
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            info.name = "ClassIdsHavingLevels";
            break;
   ........
```

**So Confusions **

1. Am I setting the propertyInfo and setProperty  i right way ?
2. if there is no problem in above point then why the error is occuring again and again .

Please help me I am stuck here from so many days. Thanks in advance

> **Note:**  I am not sharing the request building method as it is normal way of sending the complex object. and my request goes successfully if I do not set the Integer list to property Index 13 as mentioned above.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? I did it in a different way. I made a class that `extends Vector<String> and implements KvmSerializable`` especially for my integer array.

Comment: how did you do that ?